# PHP: Yii: move_uploaded_file(/IMG-8746.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: yii, permissions, move-uploaded-file

Don't know how to fix this error, eventough I read several articles and watched a few videos. I already made my @web directory read- and writeable with chmod 777 -R.

I am able to upload files in different locations out of the @web folder. Unfortunately, I am unable to display pictures at my website, which are out of the @web directory.

Please help :)

Comment: Please write full code snippet with error code so that we can assist

Comment: try setting the ownership explicitly to the group php is running with
chown -R www-data:www-data ./path/to/destination
chmod -R 0755 ./path/to/destination

Comment: At first sight I would say you might be mixing up `@web` and `@webroot` aliases but I can't confirm that without seeing the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your path should be proper with needed permission. Try with adding static path and check if it works then add dynamic path